# Azure SDK for Androidの参考ドキュメントについて

Tags: java, android

AndroidからAzureSDKを利用して、Blob StorageへデータのIOを実現したいです。
以下の条件を基に、AndroidアプリとAzure Blob Storageのデータ連携アプリを開発しようとしていますが、開発ドキュメントを見つけられず実現出来ておりません。

- 動作環境
  OS：Android10、11
  開発言語：Java
- 開発環境
  Android Studio 4.1.3

Pythonでの実装は以下のドキュメントから問題なく対応できました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Android版でも同様のドキュメントは無いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

こちらのAndroidですかね
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/reference

APIライブラリ本体は多分これ。
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android
直接、Gradle経由、Maven経由いずれのダウンロード方法もざっくりとは説明されてます。

少しググったところヒットする非公式のAndroid版のサンプルは
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-legacy
とほぼ同様のことをしていたので、APIの内容はJava v8版相当なのだと思います。

```
String connectionString = "ほげほげ";
String containerNameString = "ふがふが";
String blobReferenceString = "hogehoge.bmp";

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerNameString);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobReferenceString);
// blob.upload(...)
// あるいは
// blob.uploadFromFile(...)
// など
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
情報不足で申し訳ありません。利用を考えていたSDKは以下となります。
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-android

Comment: そちらのリポジトリにある様に、BETA版ですのでライブラリを直接読み進められる人向けかと思います。Android版やJavaのライブラリはv8から紆余曲折をへてv10、v11等が放棄されていますので、慣れないのでしたら今の段階では情報の多いライブラリを使用したほうが無難かと思われますがいかがでしょうか。